# make overscroll area under Web View transparent?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I have a WebView that is working perfectly. When I scroll it (up or down) past it's content I see a white area "Behind" the web page. (had an image here, but couldn't post due to being new).

I would like to set the overscroll color to clear.

To be precise I have played with setting the WebView background to transparent, and that does not achieve the desired result. That makes the entire page clear to the background of my app. I only want to see the app background if the user has scrolled past the contents of the window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourwebviewname.opaque=NO;
```

Comment: opaque is not a property of a WebView. There is a method called "isOpaque", but that does not set the value, just evaluates state.